# How to remove Anchors from Template File in PHPWord

Tags: php, codeigniter, ms-word, phpword

I am using `PHPWORD` for report generation in Microsoft Word. I have created a Template File with multiple Anchors like this

> ${ABOUT}
>
> TEXT
>
> ${/ABOUT}

However, I would like to remove the Anchors {ABOUT} and {/ABOUT} in the final report.

Any idea how to do it ? Is there a function similar to `str_replace` in `PHPWORD`?

Answer (score 0):

With this little information I'm not really sure what your use case is for having the template block in your document in the first place? But you should be able to remove the anchors by simply cloning the template once.

```
$templateProcessor->cloneBlock('ABOUT');
```